# How to conserve menu when creating an Intent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am very new to Java / Android programing. Android Studio offered me a layout that consists in a menu like such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_empty"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Empty" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_quotes"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Quotes" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_info"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Information" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

For now I'm trying to make the second item of the menu work, here's where I am when I press it:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_empty) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_quotes) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuotesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);  // start the newly created Intent
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_info) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

As you can see I create an Intent that leads me to `QuotesActivity`, but once I enter this page, the menu that was on the top left (classic clickable android menu) disappears.

Here's the `activity_quotes.xml` file for the `QuotesActivity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.kade_c.plus.QuotesActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/quote_welcome"
        android:id="@+id/textView_quotes"
        android:layout_marginTop="236dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/quotes_button"
        android:id="@+id/button_quotes"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_marginBottom="184dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What can I do to give the user the possibility to access the menu at any given time? Additionally, if you see flaws in how I proceed, please let me know !

Thank you.

Comment: Menu on the left disappears because now you are in the new `Activity` `QuotesActivity` and Menu was in the previous `Activity`. You should explore how Fragments work and implement a Fragment view for Quotes instead of a new Activity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look further into Fragments.